# Необычная анимация svg path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Как можно сделать точно такой же hover-эффект, как на [этом сайте](https://aghost.store/shop/welcome) при наведении на svg-иконку закрытия меню?

HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width='50' height='50' x="0px" y="0px"  viewBox="0 0 52 51.8" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M7.7,7.8L26,26.1"/>
  <path d="M7.5,44.5l17-17"/>
  <path d="M44.4,44.5L26,26.1"/>
  <path d="M44.4,7.7L30.2,21.9"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
    fill: none;
}
path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #3498db;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Была идея сделать как-то так, но не очень она рабочая:

```
var svg = document.querySelector(".elem");
    var lines = svg.querySelectorAll("path");

$("svg").hover(function() {

        for (let i = 0; lines.length > i; i++) {
            let path = lines[i].getTotalLength();
            lines[i].style.strokeDashoffset = path;
            lines[i].style.strokeDasharray = path;
        }

        var int = setInterval(draw, 150);

        function draw() {
            for (let i = 0; lines.length > i; i++) {
                let path = lines[i].getTotalLength();
                if (path <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(int);
                } else {
                    path += 20 * (-1);
                    lines[i].style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Так нужен только hover или полностью с открытием/закрытием?

Comment: только Hover нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
$('.elem').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var delay = 30;
  var paths = $(this).find('path');
  paths.each(function() {
    var line = this;
    var length = this.getTotalLength();
    setTimeout(function() {
      line.style.strokeDasharray = length;
      line.setAttribute('class', 'animated');
      line.style.strokeDasharray = -length;
      line.style.strokeDashoffset = -length;
      setTimeout(function() {
        line.style.strokeDasharray = -length * 2;
        line.style.strokeDashoffset = -length * 2;
      }, 350);
      setTimeout(function() {
        line.setAttribute('class', '');
        line.style.strokeDasharray = length;
        line.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
      }, 650);
    }, delay);
    delay = delay + 30;
  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

path {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

svg path.animated {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" class="elem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width='50' height='50' x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 52 51.8" xml:space="preserve">
  <path d="M7.7,7.8L26,26.1"/>
  <path d="M7.5,44.5l17-17"/>
  <path d="M44.4,44.5L26,26.1"/>
  <path d="M44.4,7.7L30.2,21.9"/>
 </svg>
```